# Is there an Object.properties() corresponding to Object.keys()?

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy, concise way to get an array of the property *values* of an object, something akin to `Object.keys()`?

So something much simpler than the following code, for instance:

```
function objProps (obj) {
    var props = [],
        keys = Object.keys(obj),
        len = keys.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        props.push(obj[keys[i]]);
    }

    return props;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` plus `map`:

```
var values = function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k){return obj[k]});
};
```